# Can dates can be considered monotonically in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids) that:

> Do not use monotonically increasing document IDs such as:

```
Customer1, Customer2, Customer3, ...
Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, ...
```

I plan to use document IDs such:

```
2023-09-01, 2023-09-02, 2023-09-07, ...
```

The dates are not always consecutive. It can be or cannot be. Can be these dates be considered monotonically?

Comment: Yes it can be considered monotically increasing IDs. However note that the hotspotting problem normally occurs at high read or write rates.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So if I have a collection that is only accessed/updated by a single user a few times a day, that won't be a problem, right?

Comment: Yes it **shouldn't** be a problem, but I would recommend following Doug's comment: "It's better to use random IDs, ..."

Comment: @RenaudTarnec One more quick question. Is this practice forbidden in the Realtime Database too? Or there I can use consecutive nodes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a similar limit for the RTDB. Here is the doc on the RTDB limits: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits. FYI, note that if you create a set of nodes with a series of integers as keys the RTDB will consider it as an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any time you have a series of sorted values that increment over a small range, that is considered monotonically increasing for the purpose of gauging the write rate limit for indexes in Firestore.  This is because they will all cause writes on the same shard of the index that handles that range of values.

Also I would strongly urge you not to use data as document IDs.  It's better to use random IDs, and create an index on the timestamp values instead, if you need to sort and filter on them. This will prevent other future problems with your app when you need to change the schema or the way you organize data.